# Why does moving the array map of props outside the render function not work in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, es6-map

The example below works just fine, I'm mapping the props array in the render function.

```
class Calendar extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
           <div>
                { this.props.events.map((event, idx) => {
                    return <li key={idx}>{event.title}</li>
                })}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I move the array map into another function is no longer works.

```
class Calendar extends Component {

    handleEvents(){
        this.props.events.map((event, idx) => {
            return <li key={idx}>{event.title}</li>
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                { this.handleEvents() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you just forgot to return from your function

```
class Calendar extends Component {

    handleEvents(){
        // here.
        return this.props.events.map((event, idx) => {
            return <li key={idx}>{event.title}</li>
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                { this.handleEvents() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that. Couldn't see it